# Existe algo semelhante ao WITH(NOLOCK) do SQL SERVER no ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Descobri há pouco tempo no SQL SERVER a opção de não bloquear tabelas para inserção enquanto faço a leitura de alguns dados, e com isso ganhar alguma performance em algumas situações específicas.

Pesquisei, mas não encontrei nada semelhante no ORACLE. Alguém sabe dizer com propriedade se realmente não existe?

Ou caso exista, como seria para utilizar?

Comment: É algo BEM, mas BEM "gambioso", mas dentro de um contexto de uma PL/SQL você pode usar `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION`, acho que é esse comportamento que você tá querendo. Eu usei isso numa stored procedure que hoje está em produção num cliente e os demônios da programação me assombram até hoje.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo essa [pergunta no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210171/effect-of-nolock-hint-in-select-statements), o ganho de desempenho ocorre quando o **NOLOCK** é utilizado na cláusula `SELECT`.

A resposta para o Oracle é: Não, não existe.

Conforme a documentação da versão `12c` (em inglês):

> O banco de dados Oracle não permite "leitura suja" (*dirty read*), que ocorre quando uma transação lê dados de outra transação que ainda não terminou (*uncommitted*).

O Oracle trata automaticamente o [nível de isolamento](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT1319) das consultas com objetivo de obter o melhor desempenho e, ao mesmo tempo, garantir a consistência e integridade dos dados.

No link para a documentação, há uma explicação detalhada sobre o assunto:

[9 Data Concurrency and Consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT020)

No fórum da Oracle há uma pergunta antiga, mas parecida com esta.

Algumas das respostas explicam porque esse conceito acima é importante para permitir a  escalabilidade do banco de dados (Oracle):

[READ UNCOMMITTED or NOLOCK on Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/656190?start=0&tstart=0)